# Sallen-Key LPF Q factor and gain

Tags: filter, sallen-key

[image]

Welcome all. I need some advice with Sallen-Key topology. I used Analog Devices tool for my design and I admit it nice quick and easy. However, I am struggling with one detail. When studied control systems I remember fact that difference between Bessel Butterworth Chebyshev and Elliptic filter is polynomial. In Sallen-key we control what type of filter it is by changing damping factor. As far I remember we can use following formula: Q=1/(3-A) and that damping factor = 2/Q. Assuming that these are correct.

1. Is my assumption that after appropriate components are selected for particular frequency (R1,R2,C1,C2) I can change type of filter by simply changing the ratio of R4/R3 as A=1+(R4/R3).
2. If first statement is correct, how does Analog Devices filter tool achieve different low pass filters using only unity gain op-amp arrangement?

Comment: duping factor? dumping factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to 1**: Yes, the gain A determines the pole-Q of the filter response and, hence, the particular approximation (Bessel, Butterworth, Chebyshev,...) - assuming all other values fixed. But note that the mentioned "particular frequency" is NOT the 3dB-cutoff frequency.

It is the "pole frequency" which remains constant during tuning of Q (via A). The 3dB-frequency will NOT remain constant. (More than that, the mentioned expression Q=1/(3-A) is valid for the equal-component case only!!)

**Answer to 2:** For unity gain, the pole-Q (and with it the characteristic) is determined as follows: **Q=SQRT(krkc)/(1+kr)** with kr=R2/R1 and kc=C2/C1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I see difference between two approaches variable gain “A” and unity gain. Same can be achieved using both methods. If I could ask follow up question. 
1. Is Bessel, Butterworth or Chebyshev configuration only depending on Q? In other words, by varying the Q we change type of the filter? 
2. By pole frequency in simple way we could say position of a spike in case of high Q?

Comment: To 1): Yes, the mentioned three types differ in the pole-Q only (with the same pole frequency wp, but with different cut-off frequencies). To 2): Not exactly ....the pole frequency wp is rather close to the peak but not identical. Here is the formula: Fpeak=Fp*SQRT(1-1/2Q²) with Fp=wp/2Pi. The pole frequency wp is the point where the phase shift is -90 deg.

Comment: What is the quality factor of a 2nd order high pass filter based on sallen key topology?

Comment: Depends on filter response type (Buterworth, Bessel, Chebyshev....)

Answer (score 0):

> *dumping factor = 2/Q. Assuming that these are correct.*

It's called damping factor not duping or dumping and no, what you have written is not [correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor): -

$$\zeta \text{ or "damping factor"} = \dfrac{1}{2Q}$$

1. Yes
2. The damping factor is commonly changed by altering the ratio of the two capacitors (for instance). Or you can change the resistor ratio

Because the two values are multiplied together to contribute to the un-damped natural frequency, increasing one while decreasing the other will change damping (or Q) without altering the frequency.

Comment: Just a small comment (clarification): The lowpass response is characterized by the "pole frequency" (not "resonant" frequency, which applies to a bandpass response only). The pole frequency wp is the frequency where the phase shift of the transfer function is exactly 90 deg.

Comment: Yes, that's a more appropriate name. However, I'll change it to un-damped natural frequency as that is the term I would have used if I'd thought about it more. @LvW

Comment: Thank you for your reply! @LvW provided formula for Q in circuit where Cs and Rs are not equal and it definitely cleared some of my uncertainties!

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that Q=1/(3-A) so the type of filter is set by the gain or R3 & R4. Note that the gain must be less than 3.

For a Butterworth filter configured like this (with gain as opposed to unity gain) the cut-off freq is 1/(2*pi*RC).

For Bessel & Chebyshev, in addition to altering the gain, there is a scaling factor, so fc = 1/(2*pi*RC * Cn). Cn can be obtained from the tables in Horowitz & Hill Pg 408. In fact this is all well documented there.

So the advantage of having gain in the filter is that both the Rs and both the Cs can be the same values. This simplification is lost with the unity gain version.

EDIT

For a 2 pole Butterworth filter A, the gain which is set by R3 & R4, must be equal to 1.586.

Q = 1/(3 - 1.586) = 0.707

0.707 is the Q of a 2 pole Butterworth filter.

Comment: No - the expression Q=1/(3-A) applies to the equal-componenet case only!!

Comment: See edit above.- The equal component case must have gain.

Comment: Yes - of course, However, the questioner`s design is NOT for equal components (nevertheless, he has mentioned an expression for Q which does NOT correspond to his design). That is my only point. Just for clarification.

Comment: I see the point you are making. When I have designed Sallen & Key Butterworth with gain I have always done it for the reason of simplifying the design process and making the Rs and Cs same value and making the cut-off freq = 1/2piRC. Very straight forward.

Comment: Thank you all for reply. This clears a lot of confusion. Sadly, materials I researched did not state the fact that components need to be equal for this approach.